# How to let the Tkinter textarea accept dropping an external file on Python 3.X?

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, python-3.x, tkinter

I googled some drag and drop tutorial, most of them is about drag and drop the internal element, within the application. But I would like to drop an external file on the textarea, it can displays back the file path to me, it will be nice, but how can I do so? Thanks? Any ideas?

PS: Using python3.X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'd already take a look at the TkDND extension for Tkinter.
Looking at its docs seems like it has some support for drag and drop external targets too:

> "For example under windows the type "FILENAME" can be used in order to
>   receive a single filename from the Explorer or the type "NetscapeURL"
>   can be used in order to receive a bookmark drop from Netscape
>   Navigator. Under Unix, the type "FILE_NAME" can be used in order to
>   receive a filename from a Motif application."

Says the docs at: http://klappnase.bubble.org/TkinterDnD/TkinterDnD_manual.html

You should try this if you really need to use Tkinter.

Otherwise, for better results and possibilities, I would advise you to use a more complete GUI framework like Qt which has bindigs for drop events natively.